# Delphi - Juntar arquivos PDF

Tags: delphi, pdf

Necessito que na seguinte procedure consiga juntar uns arquivos em PDF.

```
procedure Tservermain.reportmaster_relatorioReports(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  with reportmaster_relatorio.Reports do
   begin
    Add(RelatorioCapa.QuickRep1);
    Add(RelatorioInfo.QuickRep1);
    Add(RelatorioConclusao.QuickRep1);

   end;
end;
```

Atualmente ele junta as varias páginas e cria este relatorio, mas agora necessito que ele acrescente mais 2 folhas em PDF.

Obrigado!

PS: andei a testar a seguinte forma:

```
Add(Caminho + '\PDF\' + 'Doc1.pdf');
```

E deu o seguinte erro: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'ShortString'

Comment: quais bibliotecas/tecnolgias vc esta usando pra gerar esse PDF, isso seria a geração de um relatório?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um componente de terceiro para esta finalidade, aqui utilizamos o *Gnostice PDFtoolkit*

Para fazer o merge é algo como...

```
var
  vArquivos: TStringList;
begin
  vArquivos := TStringList.Create;
  vArquivos.Add(arquivo_entrada..);
  vArquivos.Add(arquivo_entrada..);

  PDFDocument.MergeDocs(vArquivos);
  PDFDocument.SaveToFile(arquivo_saida);

  FreeAndNil(vArquivos);
end;
```